# XSLT parse document($file) before use in a key

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I've got a stupid question.

I am loading an external document, and then using it to add an attribute to a certain element in the main document. A bit like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="dictstrings" select="document($dictionary_file)"/>
<xsl:key name="ui_ids" match="DICT_ENTRY" use="LANG_ENTRY"/>

<!--Identity template, copies all content -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

 <!--Template for uicontrol that provides custom behavior -->
 <xsl:template match="uicontrol[key('ui_ids', ., $dictstrings)]">  
     <xsl:apply-templates select="key('ui_ids', ., $dictstrings)"/>
 </xsl:template>
```

This matches the appropriate LANG_ENTRY element(s) in the external document to the corresponding `uicontrol`  element in the main document. (I have another `xsl:template` command that adds the DICT_ID attribute.) All good so far.

My problem is that sometimes the LANG_ENTRY element in my $dictionary_file starts with an extraneous ampersand.  Like so:

```
  <DICT_ENTRY DICT_ID="21625">
    <LANG_ENTRY><![CDATA[Test list]]></LANG_ENTRY>
  </DICT_ENTRY>
  <DICT_ENTRY DICT_ID="2163">
    <LANG_ENTRY><![CDATA[&Insert new test]]></LANG_ENTRY>
  </DICT_ENTRY>
```

I'd like to strip this ampersand out. Otherwise, the match won't work.

I was trying to do this, in a vague dreamy haze:

```
<xsl:variable name="dictstrings">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="document($dictionary_file)"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

and then have a template that caught the LANG_ENTRY

```
<xsl:template match="LANG_ENTRY[starts-with(.,'&amp;')]">
    <xsl:element name="LANG_ENTRY">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(.,2)"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

But, as you know, it objects to the declaration of the dictstrings variable, now, saying

```
XTDE0640: Circular variable or parameter declaration
```

How should I go about parsing and editing the external document nodes, before using them in the key() function?

I am also nervous about making sure the context is correct between the main and the external document, but I haven't got to that problem yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need to "edit" the external nodes as such, simply ensure that the `use` expression in the key definition strips off the leading ampersand, if there is one, when it constructs the key value:

```
<xsl:key name="ui_ids" match="DICT_ENTRY" use="replace(LANG_ENTRY, '^&amp;', '')"/>
```

(You haven't said so explicitly but I assume you're in XSLT 2.0 given you're using variables in `match` patterns and the three-argument form of the `key` function).

Comment: Thank you. Very simple and works perfectly. I'm still learning all this.